# How to connect to Restful API via PHP? CDK Global Lightspeed API

Tags: php, rest, restful-authentication

I have been provided the following documentation: https://www.scribd.com/document/352616763/Lightspeed-Web-Service-Developer-Guide and am trying to connect via PHP and return data from the API.

The documentation does provide examples of results that should be returned, but doesn't provide any basic examples of retrieving that data in the first place.

I've attempted using information at the following resources to connect, but am hitting a dead end:

[How to access RESTful API via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999323/how-to-access-restful-api-via-php)

[connect to RESTful api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507758/connect-to-restful-api)

https://www.allphptricks.com/create-and-consume-simple-rest-api-in-php/

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/understanding-using-rest-api/

Not super experienced when it comes to accessing data in this manner, though I have made extensive use of the WordPress REST API in the past.

Am I being really dumb here or is the documentation lacking fundamental information required to make a connection and get data back? Would very much appreciate if someone can provide a working code example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself now:

```
$login = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';
$url = 'https://int.lightspeedadp.com/lsapi/Part/76010000';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);  

$parts = json_decode($result);

foreach($parts as $part){
    echo '<div>'.$part->Description.'</div>';
}
```